how to use efficiently rotation matrix in numpy to compute new coordinates along a circle (avoiding for loops)?
I would like improve the script below.
The goal of the script is to compute different coordinates corresponding to several angles. This corresponds to rotate one point around x axis and for each step angle retrieve the coordinates.
import numpy as np

# rotating angle
th = np.pi
# starting point (x,y,z coordinates)
ori = [1,1,0]
# how many steps ?
step = 10 

# initializing coordinate matrix
# with the starting point

coords = np.array(ori)

# vector containing angles
angles = np.linspace(0,th,step)

# compute new position for each angle in vector angles
for angle in angles: 
    # adapt Rot matrix with angle
    Rot = np.array([
        [np.cos(angle),-np.sin(angle),0],
        [np.sin(angle),np.cos(angle),0],
        [0, 0, 1]
    ])
    # compute new coordinate
    new_coord = ori @ Rot
    # add new coordinate to coords matrix
    coords = np.append(coords, new_coord)
# change shape of coords for esthetical purpose
coords= np.reshape(coords,(-1,3))
print(coords)

I would like to avoid the loop !
Does anyone have an idea for using only matrix calculations to achieve the same result?
Thank you

It won't avoid a loop, but you don't have to keep calculating rotation matrices. The angles are equi-spaced, so create a rotation matrix for that angle increment and keep applying the SAME matrix to the last-calculated point to get the new one. Alternatively, since you are rotating about the z-axis and the original point is in the x,y plane then you could just use the real and imaginary parts of complex numbers.

The loop is certainly not the biggest issue here. coords = np.append(coords, new_coord) is a performance issue if the number of iteration (N) is big since it creates N growing arrays resulting in a O(n**2) time (bad). To fix this, you can simply add the temporary items to a list and then create a Numpy array from the list.

Calling np.cos(angle) and np.sin(angle) twice is sub-optimal. You can just create a variable. This is independent of vectorizing the loop. CPython do not optimize codes (it is interpreted and very dynamic so it cannot do much).

While it might be possible to vectorize the loop by pre-computing all matrices and play with higher dimensional array, it will be clearly inefficient since Numpy is really not optimized internally for very small array computations anyway. BLAS are not optimized for that either. I strongly advise you to use Numba or Cython (only with views) to speed this up. You can optimize the code so to avoid multiplications by 0 or 1 which are useless. The final code should be at least 10x faster than an optimized Numpy code and certainly >50x faster than your current code.

By the way, a [[x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], ...] layout is fundamentally inefficient in this case on all mainstream CPUs (since >20 years). You should use 3 arrays instead if you care about performance. The reason the later is generally faster is due to SIMD units. For more information, please read AoS vs SoA.

It shouldn't be hard create a 3d  Rotarray for allanglesand apply it with@`.  The angles 'batch' dimension should be first.

@JérômeRichard Regarding your comment about the array structure, would [[x1, x2, ...], [y1, y2, ...], [z1, z2, ...]] be more efficient or is it still better to break them out into 3 separate arrays?

@jared It is also OK that way on most CPUs (the alignment should be better with 3 arrays but on x86-64 CPUs, alignement is generally not really a problem).

BTW, you are currently rotating about the z axis, not the x axis.

Replacing the array append with a list appent reduces timeit times from 597 to 427 us.  But this for angles, loop size, of 10 - not a whole lot.  Small number of loops on a complex task are not that bad, speed wise.

Your code, run with %%timeit in an ipython session times as
597 µs ± 1.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

The coords is a (11,3) array.  The first 2 rows are identical, the ori you first put in it, and the 0 angle rotation.
Replacing the array append with a faster list append produces the same thing, with a modest time improvement
... 
...:   coords = [ori]

...: for angle in angles: 
...:     ...
...:     coords.append(new_coord)
...: # change shape of coords for esthetical purpose
...: coords= np.reshape(coords,(-1,3))

Modest time improvement:
427 µs ± 2.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

We can calculate a rot matrix for all angles at once:
def rotmat(angles):
    Rot = np.zeros((len(angles),3,3))
    Rot[:,2,2] = 1
    Rot[:,[0,1],[0,1]] = np.cos(angles)[:,None]
    Rot[:,[0,1],[1,0]] = np.sin(angles)[:,None]*[-1,1]
    return Rot

And apply it with ori@rotmat(angles)
In [64]: %%timeit 
    ...: # rotating angle
    ...: th = np.pi
    ...: # starting point (x,y,z coordinates)
    ...: ori = [1,1,0]
    ...: # how many steps ?
    ...: step = 10 
    ...: 
    ...: # initializing coordinate matrix
    ...: # with the starting point
    ...: 
    ...: # vector containing angles
    ...: angles = np.linspace(0,th,step)
    ...: rot = rotmat(angles)
    ...: coords = ori @ rot
    ...: 
    ...: 
143 µs ± 364 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

This matches your original coords (except it doesn't duplicate the first row):
np.allclose(original_coords[1:],coords)

That's a decent time improvement by using standard numpy 'vectorization' - using whole array methods where possible.  numba etc can improve things more.

Thank you to everyone who participated !
@hpaulj
wow great  !!
I would never have thought of it (I don't have much experience using 3D tables in this way) => many thanks !
could you please explain more in depth :
Rot[:,[0,1],[0,1]] = np.cos(angles)[:,None] and Rot[:,[0,1],[1,0]] = np.sin(angles)[:,None]*[-1,1]

Rot[:,[0,1],[0,1]] indexing selects a (n,2) block.  np.cos(angles)[:,None] makes a (n,1) array, which by broadcasting can fit in the (n,2).  The sin expression multiplies (n,1) with (2) to produce (n,2).  Again by the rules of broadcasting.  This was the easiest way I could think of to write the (n,3,3) array, not necessarily the computationally optimal one.
